# Public property List needs to Concat 2 types with inheritance

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I have 2 lists: one of type A and one of type Aa. type Aa is inherited from type A.
So:

```
List<A> listA = new List<A>();
List<Aa> listAa = new List<Aa>();
```

with

```
class Aa : A
```

I have:

```
public property Lists<A>
{
  get
   {
    List<A> newList = new List<A>();
    //return concat of both lists
    foreach(List l in listA)
    {
      newList.Add(l);
    }
    foreach(List l in listAa)
    {
      newList.Add(l);
    }
}
```

Can I somehow use Concat instead of the foreach loop? i.e.

```
get
{
  return listA.Concat(listAa);
} // this doesn't work
```

And secondly, how do I do the set part of the property?

```
set
{
  //figure out the type of variable value and put into appropriate list?
}
```

Comment: @Obalix: From the original, I'm not 100% sure these were generic lists, and not System.Collections.List...

Comment: @Reed Copsey: just did the formatting ... :-) ... and according to the OP from Bernard the Lists are defined as List<A> and List<Aa>.

Comment: Ahh, okay - wasn't obvious from the original text, which had: " List listA = new List();", etc... suggesting non-generic usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are generic lists, like so:

```
List<A> listA;
List<Aa> listAa;
```

You should be able to do:

```
public IList<A> Lists
{
    get 
    {
        return listA.Concat(listB.Cast<A>()).ToList();
    }
}
```

The call to [Enumerable.Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) will allow you to convert the `List<Aa>` into an `IEnumerable<A>` (since Aa is a subclass of A), which will make Concat work.  You can then convert this back into a `List<A>` by calling `ToList()`.

As for the property setter - I would not recommend making this property contain a property setter.  This is going to behave in a VERY non-standard manner.  Instead, it would most likely be a much better idea to make a custom method for handling setting the lists.

If you're going to pass in a single list, containing `Aa` and `A` classes, you could use something like:

```
public void SetLists(IEnumerable<A> newElements)
{
    this.listA.Clear();
    this.listAa.Clear();
    foreach(A aElem in newElements)
    {
        Aa aaElem = aElem as Aa;
        if (aaElem != null)
            this.listAa.Add(aaElem);
        else
            this.listA.Add(aElem);
    }
}
```

In this case, doing the loop will actually be more efficient than trying to use LINQ for setting these arrays, since you're going to have some odd filtering required.

Answer (score 0):

also, it will work in .net 4.0 without a cast because of covariance